# Are there any docs(detail) about how to integrate our own LDAP to DS?

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

We want to use our own ldap in dolphinscheduler to login,so I need more detail docs to use it! thanks！

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at this Web I do not know if it is helpful
http://106.75.43.194:8888/dolphinscheduler/doc.html

Comment: thanks,but I can't find anything about LDAP in the url

Comment: Sorry. Then I guess you'll just have to look at the source code

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can refer this two class `LoginHandlerInterceptor` and `LoginController`.
If you don’t want to store user information in the `t_ds_user` table, major changes may be required. But I think the community may refactor this part of the code later to make it easier to access the three-party permission system.